# How to test if else in redux saga

Tags: redux-saga

```
export function * addNewCity({city}) {
    try {
        const weatherData = yield call(getWeather, city);
        const isDuplicateLocation = yield select(isDuplicateCity, city);

        if(!isDuplicateLocation) {
            yield put(fetchCityData((weatherData && weatherData.data) || {}));
        } else {
            yield put(errors(['Duplicate Location']));
            yield delay(DISPLAY_ERROR_TIME);
            yield put(clearErrors());
        }
    } catch(err) {
        yield put(errors(['Invalid Location']));
        yield delay(DISPLAY_ERROR_TIME);
        yield put(clearErrors());
    }
};
```

I'm trying to get to else condition in testing not sure what is the best approach to do this. Mocking selector `isDuplicateCity` doesn't seem to work.

In summary, how to make `isDuplicateCity` return true while testing.

link to the [file](https://github.com/GurpreetSran/react-express-weather-report/blob/master/client/src/redux/sagas/weatherSaga.test.js).

Comment: You have to put the mocked value into the next `next` call. E.g. `expect(generator.next(true).value).toEqual(put(fetchCityData({})));`

Comment: If `call(getWeather, city)` is an async function then your testing function should be async too.

Comment: You might also be interested in the `cloneableGenerator` utility function. It will help you to avoid going through the whole saga multiple times https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#cloneablegeneratorgeneratorfunc